# Associative arrays and binding parameters

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I've gotten a little confused with the `PDO::prepare` functions.

I have something like this

```
array('user_email'=>'hello@net.com','user_pass'=>'password')
```

and i'd like to translate it into something like this

```
INSERT INTO user_info (user_email, user_pass) VALUES (hello@net.com, password)
```

using parameterized queries with PDO (or mysqli, I'm open to suggestions). 
Another idea -

```
array('uid'=>'10', 'first_name'=>'robert', 'last_name'=>'jones')
array("email", "number")
```

into

```
SELECT email, number FROM t1 WHERE uid=10 AND first_name=robert AND last_name=jones
```

I know the answer lies somewhere with `PDO::prepare` and `call_user_func_array`, but I've gotten really confused on how the latter function works, and would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I'm confused, and maybe you are too. Here is a simple example:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND date = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, '2009-04-04'));
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Or:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT table VALUES(:foo, :bar)");
$sth->bindParam(":foo", $foo);
$sth->bindParam(":bar", $bar);
```

Or:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info (user_email, user_pass) VALUES (:email, :pass)");
$sth->execute(array(':email' => 'foo@example.org', ':pass' => '1234'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

PDOStatement::execute() works with parameters markers, so you have to construct query before calling PDO::prepare().

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use call_user_func_array(). PDOStatement::execute() takes associative arrays by default.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT fld FROM tbl WHERE fld=:parameter1 AND fld2=:parameter2");
$stmt->execute(array(":parameter1" => "value1", ":parameter2" => "value2"));
...
```

http://se.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php